# Notepad++ Replacing Text Between Two Strings Using Regular Expression

Tags: notepad++

Got something like this

`<foo@boo.com>foo@boo.com`

`<info@foo2.com>info@foo2.com`

I want to select all the text that is between every <> in the whole script and replace it with a definite value.
I also want to leave out all the text that is not in between <> unaffected.

Tried using this expression
<.*> 
but then the whole script got selected, including the text that is not between <>

Comment: try `<.*?>`. `*` is greedy whereas `*?` is lazy.

Comment: Works fine, thanks

Answer (score 8):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=<).+?(?=>)`
- Replace with: `New_value`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=<)      # positive lookbehind, make sure we have "<" before
.+?         # 1 or more any character but newline
(?=>)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have ">" after
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

[Further reading](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)